# Where is the "auto submit" option?

Tags: views, 8

I have an exposed filter for one of my views and I added a drop-down select for the users to pick from.

In Views for Drupal 7 there was an Auto-Submit check box, but I can not seem to find it in Drupal 8 at all. Does anyone know where it may be hiding or how I can get the filter to auto-submit.

Answer (score 5):

While tracking the above issue is good for long-term success... if you need this functionality ASAP, here's a tiny bit of a hack to get it working with some custom javascript. Inside your theme's JS, add something like the following:

```
// Autosubmit 'view-class-here' views exposed form.
$("div.view-class-here").find("form.views-exposed-form").find("select").bind("change", function () {
  $(this).closest("form").trigger("submit");
}).end().find("input[type='submit']").addClass("visually-hidden");
```

This will do the following:

1. Look at any `select` item in a given views exposed form (for a view with a class `.view-class-here`), and trigger a submit whenever the select list is changed.
2. Hide the 'Submit'/'Apply' button associated with the exposed form.

If you want to trigger the submit on `input` fields, change the `.bind()` to use something like `input:checkbox` or `input` for any kind of input (though that might need more tweaking to make sure things don't go crazy!).

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is currently in flux, and may eventually be moved to CTools, Core, or a small module. Track issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2475595 for updates.