# Autosubmit exposed filter?

Tags: views, entities, 8

Is it possible without change in core files to display exposed filters without "Submit" button and with autosubmint functionality? I mean autosubmit form, not autocomplete.

Comment: OK I found it: turn ajax "on", change "Exposed form style" to autosubmit, hide submit button, profit.

Comment: please add in answer section so that it will remove from unanswered question list.

Comment: See this related question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183357/where-is-the-suto-submit-option

Answer (score 1):

This is not an option at the moment in Drupal 8.
This option was removed in this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1789270)
There is an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2475595) for it.
They are trying to get it into ctools right now. ( 20-10-2016 )

Answer (score 0):

turn ajax "on", change "Exposed form style" to autosubmit, hide submit button

Comment: This option is not available. Are you sure u are using Drupal 8?