# views exposed filters : how to trigger the submit on options click

Tags: 8, views

How to trigger the submit on select options click?

This would require for the end-user one click instead of two.
The button could be removed or hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

Also, this related post: [Where is the "auto submit" option?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183357/where-is-the-auto-submit-option)